# Hide image on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have this html tag to put an arbitrary image on a page.

```
<a href="example.com"><img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/....186.png" width="133" height="13" style="float:right; margin-right: 100px; margin-top: 40px;" /></a>
```

However, I dont want this image on mobile. Can this be done?

Comment: You need to do some research on css media queries :)

Comment: Please provide with any example that you have tried. We can help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to be mobile first. 
select class for your image. for example hide-mobile. then write these codes:

```
.hide-mobile
{
    display: none;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    .hide-mobile
    {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Somehow this doesn't work Saleh. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at media queries:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

To hide the image, you would need a media query with `display:none`, which is only included on a low resolution.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    img {
       display: none;
    }
}
```

EDIT: It is not a good idea to define your style inline. You should rather use a seperate css file or at least a `<style>` block in your `header`. This helps with controlling different scenarios and keep your styling consistent over multiple objects and pages.

Comment: That worked brilliant J. Starick! Many thanks! And I will keep in mind the suggestion for separate css file. Thanks again,

Comment: It is preferable to link to a non-w3schools resource, such as MDN. [Why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com)?

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I will keep that in mind in the future.